# Firefox for Windows will not load page when all other Windows and Mac browsers will

Tags: windows, firefox, connection, httpd.conf

I have a website https://www.ocetacea.net/LiftUsUpdoc/ that is accessed via another URL http://www.LiftUsUpDoc.com. The ocetacea page loads for Chrome, Edge, IE, and Opera for Windows and Safari, Chrome, Edge, IE, Firefox, and Opera for Mac (latest version in all cases), but not for Firefox for Windows. When trying to access the site on Firefox for Windows, I get:

[image]

After some research, I thought it was because my security certificate is a DV and not an EV, but I no longer think that's the case.

Can anyone tell me why this site will load in every browser but Firefox for Windows?

(Clicking on "Try Again" simply brings me back to the same "Secure Connection Failed" error message.)

Edit 1:

On the basis of @AyushKumar's comment, I added `index.php` to the end of the URL, and Firefox loaded the page properly but I don't understand why this is necessary.

This is a fragment of my `httpd.conf` file:

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
```

and it lists `index.php` as the first index filetype that ought to be looked for.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my `httpd.conf` file causing Firefox (and only Firefox for Windows) to not load my `index.php` file?

Comment: The problem seems to be with site index files or html and not with the certificate. You can try not to use any external links for images etc. and use it via downloading it on your server and see if it works.

Comment: @AyushKumar you're right--if I add index.php to the URL, Firefox loads the page properly. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Sorry i can't tell with the given info provided . Though why don't you ask it on mozilla support https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/new. Might help you with it